# Como dividir datos de una columna en varias columnas

Tags: sql-server, phpmyadmin

tengo una consulta en SQL que es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
t1.APP_NUMBER, 
t1.ALTO, 
t1.ANCHO,
t1.LARGO, 
t1.ALTO2, 
t1.ANCHO2, 
t1.LARGO2, 
t2.NUM_PACA,
t2.PROMEDIO,
t1.PROMEDIOH
FROM PMT_HISTORIAL_MP t1
inner join PMT_PROMEDIO_HUMEDAD t2 on t1.APP_NUMBER=t2.NUM_CASO
```

[image: Esta es la consulta que tengo]

Pero quiero dividir los promedios en mas columnas, por ejemplo, en donde dice: NUM_PACA cuenta cuantas pacas son, ya sea 5 o 10 entonces quisiera poner en cada columna el promedio de cada paca, por ejemplo:

*APP_NUMER |ALTO|ANCHO|LARGO|ALTO2|ANCHO2|LARGO2|PROMEDIO1|PROMEDIO2|...|PROMEDIO10|PROMEDIOH*

No importa que en algunos valores aparezca NULL cuando sean las pacas de 5 promedios,
de ante mano gracias

Comment: Eso es una tabla pivote.. pero porque querrias hacer eso en la DB?

Comment: Quisiera que la consulta de la tabla saliera así, ya que los datos los presentaré en un reporte en Excel que esté conectado a la base de datos y se actualice en tiempo real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en que lo solucione fue la siguiente y me funciono, ya que los valores nunca pasaran de 10:

```
SELECT t1.APP_NUMBER      , 
   t1.ALTO     , 
   t1.ANCHO, 
   t1.LARGO         , 
   t1.ALTO2            ,
   t1.ANCHO2 ,
   t1.LARGO2,
   t1.FECINSPECCION_LABEL, 
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 1 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA1,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 2 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA2,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 3 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA3,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 4 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA4,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 5 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA5,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 6 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA6,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 7 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA7,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 8 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA8,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 9 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA9,
   MAX( CASE WHEN t2.NUM_PACA = 10 THEN t2.PROMEDIO END) AS PACA10,
    t1.PROMEDIOH
   FROM PMT_HISTORIAL_MP t1
   inner join PMT_PROMEDIO_HUMEDAD t2 on t1.APP_NUMBER=t2.NUM_CASO
   GROUP BY t1.APP_NUMBER      , 
   t1.ALTO, 
   t1.ANCHO, 
   t1.LARGO         , 
   t1.ALTO2            ,
   t1.ANCHO2 ,
   t1.LARGO2,
   t1.FECINSPECCION_LABEL, 
   t1.PROMEDIOH;
```